# I want to click on text and display pdf in a modal

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

Currently I show the name of pdf documents in text and when clicked it calls a controller and then displays the PDF on the screen.
I would like to click but instead of opening another screen the pdf file I would like a **modal** to open with the pdf.

I wanted to know what I can change in my code to do it, I leave below the view and controller that I use.

This is my view where I show the name of the document on the screen and when I click I send as a parameter an ID of the document that I want to show on the screen.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetPDF", "Home", new { Model.Id })">
 Document Name: @Model.documentType 
</a>
```

The controller receives the file ID and calls via a function get the file information from the database, get the byte of the file and convert it to PDF.

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> GetPDF(Guid id)
        {

            var vm = new ViewModels.Home.AttachmentViewModel();
            var result = vm.GetServiceAttachment(id));

            //Function to get the file information from DB .

            
            byte[] file;
            foreach (var attachment in result)
            {
              
                  file = attachment.File;

                  byte[] byteArray = file;


               return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "application/pdf");
            }
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: That link is what I need how can I get the code to see how it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer I am not the Author (Mudassar Khan) that is the subject of this download demo https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/1261/ but this seems to be what you are after. It can be configured according to your required size etc. source is at https://www.aspsnippets.com/Handlers/DownloadFile.ashx?File=96826afb-6258-4d2a-9e75-27593f30bfdb.zip

[image]

The Problem with using Modals is not knowing a user current screen size.
To adjust for an average desktop user I would suggest the modal be wide but not too tall and be scalar by use viewport related 98% settings

```
$("#btnShow").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    title: fileName,
                    width: 1440,
                    height: 800,
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
```

also alter fixed size to

```
                        var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"98%vw\" height=\"98%vh\">";
```

To allow for the majority of users as Chromium based (Brave, Chrome, Edge etc.), If you wish to fit the PDF height ("#view=fitV") alter by add into this line

```
object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "Files/" + fileName + "#view=fitV");
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much that is great!!! just I have a last question I used to use a controller to get the pdf file like this <a href="@Url.Action("GetPDF", "Home", new { Model.Id })"> in this case how should do it to set the pdf file from the controller ?